# high resolution RTSP server on android?

Tags: android, opencv, streaming, rtsp

I'm trying to stream live video from my Android to my PC (which will make heavy OpenCV operations on the input and save the result to a file), both in the same LAN. I've tried using [libstreaming](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming) for that purpose, but the problem is I can't manage to use it to send frames in higher resolution than 240x160, which gives me poor quality - not enough for my needs. I've used H264, and when I try using higher resolutions libstreaming throws an exception that the encoders can't handle these frames.

Any ideas about how I can use libstreaming to stream high-res frames? (preferably 720p, 20+ fps).
Ideas without using libstreaming are also welcome...

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do a native C/C++ RTP or RTSP streamer with the help of FFMPEG. You could either use the API and make your own software or even run FFMPEG from command line if your Android environment allows that. You haven't mentioned your available choices (Java only, Java + JNI + C/C++) so it is hard to give an exact advice.

Answer (score 0):

I currently have the same problem. However, I managed to get some better results with libstreaming using the H263 codec. The video quality is still not completely satisfactory, yet it's 720p.
I've built my application based on the [libstreaming example 1](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming-examples#example-1), using the `RTSPServer`. Here is the relevant code:

```
private Session mSession;

[...]

mSession = SessionBuilder.getInstance()
    .setContext(getApplicationContext())
    .setAudioEncoder(SessionBuilder.AUDIO_AAC)
    .setAudioQuality(new AudioQuality(8000, 16000))
    .setVideoEncoder(SessionBuilder.VIDEO_H263)
    .setVideoQuality(new VideoQuality(1280,720,30,2000000))
    .setSurfaceView(mSurfaceView)
    .build();
```

I don't know how to handle the stream using openCV, but for instance, I was able to see it using VLC:

```
C:\>"C:\<your VLC installation path>\vlc.exe" rtsp://<your device IP address>:1234 -f
```

---

EDIT: I managed to stream at 720p using H264 encoder, and forcing the `MediaRecorder` method instead of the `MediaCodec` one. Not really sure why the second should be more preferrable or advanced than the first. The quality is more or less the same of the method I described above, but at least the jittering that occurs when you are moving fast, is disappeared.

Notice that forcing the streaming method with the `SessionBuilder` is not working:

```
mSession = SessionBuilder.getInstance()
    .setContext(getApplicationContext())
    .setAudioEncoder(SessionBuilder.AUDIO_AAC)
    .setAudioQuality(new AudioQuality(8000, 16000))
    .setVideoEncoder(SessionBuilder.VIDEO_H264)
    .setVideoQuality(new VideoQuality(1280,720,30,2000000))
    .setSurfaceView(mSurfaceView)
    .setStreamingMethod(VideoStream.MODE_MEDIARECORDER_API) //Completely ignored
    .build();
```

You have to force it in the calling url:

```
C:\>"C:\<your VLC installation path>\vlc.exe" rtsp://<your device IP address>:1234?videoapi=mr -f
```